# Gradle How to include runtimeOnly dependencies in JavaExec classpath?

Tags: gradle, runtime, classpath, javaexec-gradle-plugin

Gradle How to include runtimeOnly dependencies in JavaExec classpath?
For example,

subproject foo:

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly files('libs/hello.jar')
}
```

subproject bar:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':foo')
}

task execHello(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'compileJava') {      
     classpath = configurations.runtime         
     main 'myPackage.Hello'
}
```

the main class myPackage.Hello is defined in the libs/hello.jar that is a runtimeOnly dependency for project foo.

configurations.runtime does not contain the runtimeOnly dependency hello.jar. If I changed the runtimeOnly dependency as api dependency in project foo, it will work.

```
classpath = configurations.runtime + configuration.runtimeOnly
```

Error: runtimeOnly can not be explicitly resolved. How to add the hello.jar in the JavaExec classpath?

Comment: Are you using the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html) (`apply plugin: 'java'`) or the [Java Library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) (`apply plugin: 'java-library'`)?

Comment: java-library. compile project(":foo") is not forcing to build jar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`runtime` and `runtimeOnly` are for declaring the dependencies. To use the dependencies you should use the configuration `runtimeClasspath` as per the docs at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph.

Comment: runtimeClasspath does include runtimeOnly dependencies, but some jars from dependent projects in the classpath do not get built. i.e. task jar is not called before the jar is being used.

Comment: workaround: add dependsOn to build jar before used in runtimeClasspath.

Comment: no, `dependsOn` is the wrong way. but you would need to show me an example to be able to tell you what you did wrongly. How do you depend on those jars?

Comment: If project A depends on project B  with dependencies { compile project(':B')}, the sequence of jar tasks is not guaranteed. Is there a nice way to say that task B.jar is called before A.jar without using dependsOn?

Comment: I would need to see the build scripts. The order should be guaranteed if you made the build scripts correctly.

Comment: There is no documentation for when to use `runtime` vs `runtimeOnly`, although based on my experience, their behaviors are very different, especially when used with plugins like Spring Boot Gradle plugin. The link in your answer doesn't even mention `runtime` configuration.

Comment: Well, that's easy, because there is only one of them. If you use the java library plugin, there is `runtimeOnly`, if you use the java plugin, there is `runtime`: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N16B17